# CMake add_subdirectory neglects isystem arguments

Tags: cmake

I am trying to setup `myproj` starting from a demo. I would like to keep the demo as it is in a `subdir` of `myproj` while still sourcing all its code and system dependencies in `myproj`, but I cannot attain a proper building environment with cmake.

---

In particular I have cloned [this](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/tree/master/AABB_tree/demo/AABB_tree) in `myproj/subdir`. I can `cd subdir`, `cmake` and `make` the executable with no issues.

I have copied the main file from from `myproj/subdir` to `myproj/myprog.cpp` and created a `myproj/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project( myproj )

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/subdir)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/subdir)

add_executable( myproj myproj.cpp )
```

In this case, even if `cmake` runs fine, all of the `-isystem` paths that `myproj/subdir/CMakeLists.txt` was adding to the gcc command line when called directly, are now missing. Therefore `make` fails. What am I doing wrong? How do I bring back all the necessary paths?

Comment: Not sure how do you add `-isystem` paths, but `include_directories` issued in the subdirectory does affect on the parent directory. Please, **show** the code instead of *describing* it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the code that I added is entirely in the question, the third party code is linked in the question. There is no more code. Here is the direct link to the third party CMakeLists.txt of the repository already linked in the question: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/AABB_tree/demo/AABB_tree/CMakeLists.txt It is this file that produces the `-isystem`s, but I cannot let it produce them from my `CMakeLists.txt` in the folder above.

Comment: Why do you ever need this `-isystem` directory for your code (C++ one)? In your `CMakeLists.txt` you link nothing to your executable, this normally means that your executable uses non external libraries. Expecting that external project just included via `add_subdirectory` will add needed compiler flags for your (parent) scope - it is not how CMake works. If your project needs CGAL, then you need to tell CMake about it, either with `include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` with a **library file**, or with only `target_link_libraries` with a **target**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I can't find a way to attain proper cmake understanding. Can't I just "source" the properly maintained and fairly complicated third party `CMakeLists.txt` that brings in CGAL, Qt and everything the demo (and my project) need?

Comment: Again, you tell that `-isystem <directory>` parameter is missing. But do not tell **which one** (which directory you need to be included via `-isystem`?). Should we guess the one you need? The [AABB_tree/demo/AABB_tree/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/AABB_tree/demo/AABB_tree/CMakeLists.txt) you refer to doesn't issue `-isystem` **by itself**. Probably this parameter comes to it from some included scripts. But searching through the entire project the parameter which is not even completely *described*...

Comment: "Can't I just "source" the properly maintained and fairly complicated third party CMakeLists.txt that brings in CGAL, Qt and everything the demo (and my project) need?" - No, you cannot. You may `include()` some other script which is **intended** to bring all required definitions into your scope. But just adding external project with `add_subdirectory` - No, again, this is not how CMake project should be prepared. Many features defined in the subproject are binded to the **inner directory**, many others - to the **targets**. In the parent directory you get none of such features.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "parameter which is not even completely described..." I know as much as you do. I have all the libraries properly installed on my system. If I clone the repo above, this is the building command that cmake produces: https://pastebin.com/5D71nE98 I do not do anything special apart from running `cmake` and `make`. I have no idea how that 'CMakeLists.txt' manages to produce that, but I would just like to take it as it is and use it for my project...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215036/discussion-between-dariop-and-tsyvarev).